# using (ngModelChange) without corresponding [ngModel]

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have been experimenting with one-way and two-way binding to an input element using ngModel.

I wish to bind from view to model, in order to capture user input. I can accomplish this by creating a variable, for e.g. *someVar*, in a Component, and binding to it in the corresponding view template using *[(ngModel)]="someVar"*.

I understand that this is syntactic sugar for *[ngModel]="someVar"* and *(ngModelChange)="someVar=$event"*.

However, if i omit the model to view binding, namely *[ngModel]="someVar"*, then the value of *someVar* remains undefined.

I cannot understand this behaviour, since omitting the view to model binding does not cause any problems.

Comment: Is your question why it behaves this way or how to get a binding from the view to the model without the other way around?

Answer (score 5):

`[ngModel]` is required to use `(ngModelChange)` because it is the @Output of `ngModel` directive.

Comment: My 2 cents: if you do not need to bind a variable in (i.e. want just an output binding), you can just use `ngModel` (without square brackets and without any value assigned to).